# Python sqlite3 success on local, but failed on Github Action

Tags: python, sqlite, github-actions

Same python version, same sqlite3 version, and same file, but I just cannot pass in Github Action.

here is my github action:
https://github.com/CloudAurora/Blog/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml

and my python file: https://github.com/CloudAurora/Blog/blob/master/scripts/init_database.py

I can run this file successfully in my local linux machine:

```
Projects/Blog - [master●] » python scripts/init_database.py -r ./posts --token  xxx
sqlite version 2.6.0
INSERT_USER_STATEMENT 
    INSERT INTO User(bio, email, githubId, name)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?)
    ON CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING

INSERT_USER_STATEMENT 
    INSERT INTO User(bio, email, githubId, name)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?)
    ON CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING

Create db file in: ./prisma/dev.db, and env is set
```

But, when I push it to github, it will fail in Github Action:

```
 sqlite version 2.6.0
INSERT_USER_STATEMENT 
    INSERT INTO User(bio, email, githubId, name)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?)
    ON CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/init_database.py", line 110, in <module>
    c.execute(INSERT_USER_STATEMENT, author_info)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

you can find the full logs: https://github.com/CloudAurora/Blog/runs/899163805?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Try to print or otherwise output the SQL statements to compare them. You can also show it as properly formatted text in the question if you don't see the problem yourself.

Comment: In line 13 of your code there is `print("sqlite3.sqlite_version:", sqlite3.sqlite_version)` but I don't see a matching output.

Comment: sorry, I finally figure out, the `sqlite version` is not the sqlite binary version, and Github Action's  os `ubuntu-latest` is actually `ubuntu 18.04` so its sqlite binary version is `3.22` which is lower than my local machine's... this problem resolved when I update to `ubuntu 20.04`  thanks!

Answer (score 7):

What fixed a similar SQLite problem for me is in my YAML workflow, replacing

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

with

```
runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
```

ubuntu-latest uses Ubuntu 18.04 and the SQLite version seems to be old and have an issue.