# Pytest is failing on GitHub Actions but succeeds locally

Tags: python, sqlite, continuous-integration, containers, github-actions

## Problem and background

I've created a CLI-based application in Python that uses SQLite to store user data. It is installed for one user at a time, and there is no communication with the outside world (except for app updates) and all data is stored locally on the user's computer.

This is tested using Pytest. On my local environment, all tests are passing. However, they're failing on GitHub actions. The problem appears to be with the `RETURNING` keyword in an SQL query.

## Attempts to fix

Upon Googling, I found that a possible fix is to change the OS version (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467899/10907280). A different place also suggested different SQLite versions (https://sqlite.org/forum/info/a4dde39b614ec0b2). I've tried changing the runner environment in many ways, but it doesn't work.

- I've tried different versions of Ubuntu in the GitHub Actions thing.
- I've tried using the `container:` setting, and tried Debian, also Ubuntu 21.04.
- Tried different versions of Python.
- I've tried manually building Python, with and without each of `libsqlite3-dev` and `sqlite3` apt-get packages, and both using directly make and through pyenv.

## Environment info

From using the shell command `python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.version)"`, both the online environment and my local machine have the same version (2.6.0).

My local system is WSL 2, Ubuntu 21.04. Everything updated to the latest stable release, Python 3.10.4 via pyenv.

## Code and errors

Old version of action YAML (this fails):

```yaml
name: build and release

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    name: pytest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
      - run: pip install -r requirements.txt pytest
      - uses: cclauss/GitHub-Action-for-pytest@0.5.0
      - run: pytest
```

Latest version of the action YAML (this fails):

```yaml
name: Test, build and release

# whenever a branch or commit is pushed
on: [push]

jobs:

  # use pytest
  test:

    # used to ensure testing is done right
    env:
      DEVELOPMENT: '1'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # to avoid using old sqlite version
    container:
      image: debian:latest
      options: --user root

    steps:
      # check out repo
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # prevent from asking user for input
      - run: export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

      # install recommended tools for building Python
      - run: apt -q update
      - run: apt -q install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev git sqlite3 -y
      - run: apt -q upgrade -y

      # install pyenv
      - run: curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
      - run: exec $SHELL
      - run: ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv update

      # install and set up required Python
      - run: ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv install 3.10.2
      - run: ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv virtualenv 3.10.2 npbc
      - run: ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv local 3.10.2/envs/npbc

      # print version info (debugging)
      - run: ~/.pyenv/shims/python -V
      - run: ~/.pyenv/shims/python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.version)"

      # install pip packages
      - run: ~/.pyenv/shims/pip install -r requirements.txt pytest

      # run test
      - run: ~/.pyenv/shims/pytest -vv
```

Full error output from GitHub Actions.

```
 ~/.pyenv/shims/pytest -vv
  shell: sh -e {0}
  env:
    DEVELOPMENT: 1
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /github/home/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/envs/npbc/bin/python3.10
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /__w/npbc/npbc
collecting ... collected 21 items

test_core.py::test_get_number_of_each_weekday PASSED                     [  4%]
test_core.py::test_validate_undelivered_string PASSED                    [  9%]
test_core.py::test_undelivered_string_parsing PASSED                     [ 14%]
test_core.py::test_calculating_cost_of_one_paper PASSED                  [ 19%]
test_core.py::test_validate_month_and_year PASSED                        [ 23%]
test_db.py::test_get_papers PASSED                                       [ 28%]
test_db.py::test_get_undelivered_strings PASSED                          [ 33%]
test_db.py::test_delete_paper PASSED                                     [ 38%]
test_db.py::test_add_paper FAILED                                        [ 42%]
test_db.py::test_edit_paper PASSED                                       [ 47%]
test_db.py::test_delete_string PASSED                                    [ 52%]
test_db.py::test_add_string PASSED                                       [ 57%]
test_db.py::test_save_results FAILED                                     [ 61%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_number PASSED                                  [ 66%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_range PASSED                                   [ 71%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_CSVs PASSED                                    [ 76%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_days PASSED                                    [ 80%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_n_days PASSED                                  [ 85%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_all_text PASSED                                [ 90%]
test_regex.py::test_delivery_regex PASSED                                [ 95%]
test_regex.py::test_regex_hyphen PASSED                                  [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_add_paper ________________________________

    def test_add_paper():
        setup_db(DATABASE_PATH, SCHEMA_PATH, TEST_SQL)
    
        known_data = [
            (1, 'paper1', 0, 0, 0),
            (1, 'paper1', 1, 1, 6.4),
            (1, 'paper1', 2, 0, 0),
            (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0),
            (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0),
            (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9),
            (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4),
            (2, 'paper2', 0, 0, 0),
            (2, 'paper2', 1, 0, 0),
            (2, 'paper2', 2, 0, 0),
            (2, 'paper2', 3, 0, 0),
            (2, 'paper2', 4, 1, 3.4),
            (2, 'paper2', 5, 0, 0),
            (2, 'paper2', 6, 1, 8.4),
            (3, 'paper3', 0, 1, 2.4),
            (3, 'paper3', 1, 1, 4.6),
            (3, 'paper3', 2, 0, 0),
            (3, 'paper3', 3, 0, 0),
            (3, 'paper3', 4, 1, 3.4),
            (3, 'paper3', 5, 1, 4.6),
            (3, 'paper3', 6, 1, 6),
            (4, 'paper4', 0, 1, 4),
            (4, 'paper4', 1, 0, 0),
            (4, 'paper4', 2, 1, 2.6),
            (4, 'paper4', 3, 0, 0),
            (4, 'paper4', 4, 0, 0),
            (4, 'paper4', 5, 1, 1),
            (4, 'paper4', 6, 1, 7)
        ]
    
>       npbc_core.add_new_paper(
            'paper4',
            [True, False, True, False, False, True, True],
            [4, 0, 2.6, 0, 0, 1, 7]
        )

test_db.py:150: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

name = 'paper4', days_delivered = [True, False, True, False, False, True, ...]
days_cost = [4, 0, 2.6, 0, 0, 1, ...]

    def add_new_paper(name: str, days_delivered: list[bool], days_cost: list[float]) -> None:
        """add a new paper
        - do not allow if the paper already exists"""
    
        global DATABASE_PATH
    
        with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
    
            # check if the paper already exists
            if connection.execute(
                "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM papers WHERE name = ?);",
                (name,)).fetchone()[0]:
                raise npbc_exceptions.PaperAlreadyExists(f"Paper \"{name}\" already exists.")
    
            # insert the paper
>           paper_id = connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO papers (name) VALUES (?) RETURNING paper_id;",
                (name,)
            ).fetchone()[0]
E           sqlite3.OperationalError: near "RETURNING": syntax error

npbc_core.py:410: OperationalError
______________________________ test_save_results _______________________________

    def test_save_results():
        setup_db(DATABASE_PATH, SCHEMA_PATH, TEST_SQL)
    
        known_data = [
            (1, 1, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-01', 105.0),
            (1, 1, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-02', 105.0),
            (2, 2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-03', 51.0),
            (2, 2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-01', 51.0),
            (2, 2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-05', 51.0)
        ]
    
>       npbc_core.save_results(
            {1: 105, 2: 51, 3: 647},
            {
                1: set([date(month=1, day=1, year=2020), date(month=1, day=2, year=2020)]),
                2: set([date(month=1, day=1, year=2020), date(month=1, day=5, year=2020), date(month=1, day=3, year=2020)]),
                3: set()
            },
            1,
            2020,
            datetime(year=2022, month=1, day=4, hour=1, minute=5, second=42)
        )

test_db.py:291: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
npbc_core.py:339: in save_results
    log_ids = {
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

.0 = <dict_keyiterator object at 0x7f135e5b5350>

    log_ids = {
>       paper_id: connection.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO logs (paper_id, month, year, timestamp)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
            RETURNING log_id;
            """,
            (paper_id, month, year, timestamp)
        ).fetchone()[0]
        for paper_id in costs.keys()
    }
E   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "RETURNING": syntax error

npbc_core.py:340: OperationalError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_db.py::test_add_paper - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "RETURNING...
FAILED test_db.py::test_save_results - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "RETURN...
========================= 2 failed, 19 passed in 0.68s =========================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

## GitHub links

- The full codebase is available. At this point, I've completed most of the changes I need to make to the actual code, and push it to GitHub. https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/tree/5c529dacbef0f9a1f8915a49dcca47834204aa09
- In this branch, I'm trying to fix the online Pytest: https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/tree/ci-cd-errors

  **UPDATE:** This has now been merged and deleted. Pull request: https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/pull/24
- All this is part of an upgrade, tracked in this issue: https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/issues/20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to manually build SQLite, as from this chain on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/ulcxr0/comment/i7vryw0/?context=3

---

This is the final YAML, in the "original" runner instead of a container. Setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is required to make sure that the linker uses the correct SQLite.

```yaml
name: Test

on: [push]

jobs:

  # test with pytest
  test:
    name: pytest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # used to ensure testing directories are used, not user directories
    env:
      DEVELOPMENT: '1'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      # build SQLite from source, because I need 3.35<=
      - run: |
          wget https://sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-autoconf-3380500.tar.gz
          tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3380500.tar.gz
      - run: |
          ./configure
          make
          sudo make install
          export PATH="/usr/local/lib:$PATH"
        working-directory: sqlite-autoconf-3380500

      # run pytest
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
      - run: pip install -r requirements.txt pytest
      - run: pytest
        env:
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib
```